# Loop smoothly through multiple images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single img element:

```
<img src="img1.png" id="looping-img">
```

Is it possible to use jQuery to create a non-stop image loop 'smoothly'? It would iterating through img2.png, img3.png, ... imgn.png, then back to img1.png with a sooth fade between images.

I built a setTimeout loop that loops through img1.png to img3.png by setting a new src:

```
callN(1);

function callN(n) { 
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        $('#looping-img').attr("src", "img" + n + ".png");
        n += 1;
        n = n == 4 ? 1 : n;
        callN(n)
 } , 1000 );
}
```

But this has the problem of not being able to make smooth transitions between images.

Is a smooth transition possible?

Comment: not with simply replacing src, normally images are stacked on top of each other then you fade out then in the images

Comment: additionally you should load Events